# I have java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using itextpdf-5.5.13.2, bcpkix-jdk15on 1.66 and bcprov-jdk15to18 1.66. I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1OctetString. I have tried everything. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a lower version of the BouncyCastle library will solve your problem. Try this [version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47).

Comment: okay I just have to reload the maven generate source and update folder by right click on pom.xml -> maven -> generate source and update folder